# String parsing with TCL / Expect

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

```
\"43STX4P-2-2-C1::TRCCMP=DISABLED,J0_EX=\"\",J0_FMT=16,J0_INC=\"??????????????
?\",J0_STAT=UNSPECIFIED,MAPPINGMODE=ASYNC,CHANNEL=NONE,MODULETYPE=XS-64.2B,AINST
MR=00-10,AINSCNTDWN=00-00,LOSPROP=LASERON,AINSREF=SYSTEM,RXPOWER=-99.00,TXPOWER=
0.69,DESCR=\"\":OOS-AUMA,FAF&MT\"
   "43STX4P-2-2-C2::TRCCMP=DISABLED,J0_EX=\"\",J0_FMT=16,J0_INC=\"??????????????
?\",J0_STAT=UNSPECIFIED,MAPPINGMODE=ASYNC,CHANNEL=1550,MODULETYPE=XS-64.2B,AINST
MR=00-10,AINSCNTDWN=00-00,LOSPROP=LASERON,AINSREF=SYSTEM,RXPOWER=-99.00,TXPOWER=
-99.00,DESCR=\"\":OOS-AUMA,FAF"
   \"43STX4P-2-2-C3::TRCCMP=DISABLED,J0_EX=\"\",J0_FMT=16,J0_INC=\"??????????????
?\",J0_STAT=UNSPECIFIED,MAPPINGMODE=ASYNC,CHANNEL=1550,MODULETYPE=XS-64.2B,AINST
MR=00-10,AINSCNTDWN=00-00,LOSPROP=LASERON,AINSREF=SYSTEM,RXPOWER=-99.00,TXPOWER=
-99.00,DESCR=\"\":OOS-AUMA,FAF"
   "43STX4P-2-2-C4::TRCCMP=DISABLED,J0_EX=\"\",J0_FMT=16,J0_INC=\"??????????????
?\",J0_STAT=UNSPECIFIED,MAPPINGMODE=ASYNC,CHANNEL=1550,MODULETYPE=XS-64.2B,AINST
MR=00-10,AINSCNTDWN=00-00,LOSPROP=LASERON,AINSREF=SYSTEM,RXPOWER=-99.00,TXPOWER=
-99.00,DESCR=\"\":OOS-AUMA,FAF"
   "43STX4P-4-2-C1::TRCCMP=DISABLED,J0_EX=\"\",J0_FMT=16,J0_INC=\"??????????????
?\",J0_STAT=UNSPECIFIED,MAPPINGMODE=ASYNC,CHANNEL=1550,MODULETYPE=XS-64.2B,AINST
MR=00-10,AINSCNTDWN=00-00,LOSPROP=LASERON,AINSREF=SYSTEM,RXPOWER=-99.00,TXPOWER=
-99.00,DESCR=\"\":OOS-AUMA,FAF"
   "43STX4P-4-2-C2::TRCCMP=DISABLED,J0_EX=\"\",J0_FMT=16,J0_INC=\"??????????????
?\",J0_STAT=UNSPECIFIED,MAPPINGMODE=ASYNC,CHANNEL=1550,MODULETYPE=XS-64.2B,AINST
MR=00-10,AINSCNTDWN=00-00,LOSPROP=LASERON,AINSREF=SYSTEM,RXPOWER=-99.00,TXPOWER=
-99.00,DESCR=\"\":OOS-AUMA,FAF"
   "43STX4P-4-2-C3::TRCCMP=DISABLED,J0_EX=\"\",J0_FMT=16,J0_INC=\"??????????????
?\",J0_STAT=UNSPECIFIED,MAPPINGMODE=ASYNC,CHANNEL=1550,MODULETYPE=XS-64.2B,AINST
MR=00-10,AINSCNTDWN=00-00,LOSPROP=LASERON,AINSREF=SYSTEM,RXPOWER=-99.00,TXPOWER=
-99.00,DESCR=\"\":OOS-AUMA,FAF"
   "43STX4P-4-2-C4::TRCCMP=DISABLED,J0_EX=\"\",J0_FMT=16,J0_INC=\"??????????????
?\",J0_STAT=UNSPECIFIED,MAPPINGMODE=ASYNC,CHANNEL=1550,MODULETYPE=XS-64.2B,AINST
MR=00-10,AINSCNTDWN=00-00,LOSPROP=LASERON,AINSREF=SYSTEM,RXPOWER=-99.00,TXPOWER=
-99.00,DESCR=\"\":OOS-AUMA,FAF"
   /* RTRV-STM64 */
```

Please help me parse this string basicly what I need is this part 43STX4P-4-2-C4
I want to exctract those strings like 43STX4P-4-2-C1 43STX4P-4-2-C2 43STX4P-4-2-C3
to be used later in a variable in commands
please help me I tried everything

**EDIT**
r00t solution worked Great but It may not always be 43STX4P in the string It may look like 130SCX10-   43SCX4L-   43SCX4-

Another note is 43STX4P-2-2-C3 .. The numbers as in -2-2 may not always be a single digit

**Edit**

This is what I raeched after researching online and some luck

```
set ports [regexp -inline -all {\w*-.-[0-9]+-C[0-9]+} $rawoutput]
```

Tell me if my code has any flaws Thanks alot for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set result [regexp -all -inline {43STX4P-4-2-C.} $data]
```

later you can lindex data what you need ;)

Comment: Your solution works GREAT but I have 1 issue that I got after i expanded the script, The 43STX4P Part may not always be that It can be different but it will always look same like 43STX4P- 43SCX4-130SCX10-

Answer (score 0):

Expect can match parts of strings with regular expressions, and make the parts that matched particular sub-expressions available to scripts, something like this:

```
expect {
    -re {[""]([\dA-Z]+-\d+-\d+-C\d+)::} {
        set id $expect_out(1,string)
    }
}
```

Now, the value you are looking for is in the convenient variable `$id`. Or you've got an error due to a timeout or EOF. You've still got to figure out the rest of the code…

<sup>The `[""]` is a RE trick to make the syntax highlighting work. It's *the same* as `"` to the RE engine.</sup>